# content type for ModelAndView

Tags: spring-mvc, junit

It is my function

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/showTaskMonitorStatus.do", "/showStatusPage.do" },                                                                                                                                                     method = RequestMethod.GET)   
public ModelAndView handleShowTaskMonitorStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    -----------------------------------
    return model;
}
```

and my test case is looks like,

```
    @Test
    public void testHandleShowTaskMonitorStatus() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result =  mockMvc.perform(get("/showTaskMonitorStatus.do"))
    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()) // Print request and response
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json")) //but in this line I am getting error.(Content type not set.)
    .andReturn(); 
    --------------------------------------
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest me How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your `@RequestMapping` like so to set the correct content type:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { ... }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bohuslav Burghardt, Its working for me. Now I am not getting any error.

Comment: I have a slightly related issue. My ```@RequestMapping``` already have ```produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE```. But, I am getting content type as ```application/json;charset=UTF-8``` in test. Interestingly this happens only in case of error. For success scenario I am getting ```application/json```. I am using a custom ```ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver```.